# AutoIt. ControlSend simultaneously to few Windows with Opt("SendKeyDownDelay", 7000)

Tags: autoit

```
Local $HWNDs = WinList("Unnamed - Notepad")
Opt("SendKeyDownDelay", 7000)
For $i = 1 To $HWNDs[0][0]
   ControlSend($HWNDs[$i][1], "", "", "f")
Next
```

This code sends keypress for 7 seconds to each opened NotePad document. The problem is: it is doing in series. In other words, first Notepad will be filling 'f' for 7 seconds. Then, after it, second Notepad window will be filling 'f' key and so on. I need to make this process parallel. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
Local $HWNDs = WinList("Unnamed - Notepad")
For $i = 1 To $HWNDs[0][0]
   ControlSend($HWNDs[$i][1], "", "", "{f down}")
Next
Sleep(7000)
For $i = 1 To $HWNDs[0][0]
   ControlSend($HWNDs[$i][1], "", "", "{f up}")
Next
```